# how we can read char* in Linux

Tags: c

How can we read datatype `char*` from the user in a pipe between two processes?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define MSGSIZE 120
int main (
{
  char *msg ;
  char inbuff[MSGSIZE];
  int p[2];
  int ret;
  pipe(p);
  ret = fork();

  if(ret != 0){
    close(p[0]);
    printf("Please Enter the msg\n");
    scanf("%s",msg);
    printf("I am the parent sending a msg %s\n",msg);
    write(p[1],msg,MSGSIZE);
  }
  else
  {
    sleep(10);
    close(p[1]);
    read(p[0],inbuff,MSGSIZE);
    printf("\nI am the child with msg %s",inbuff);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My problem is that whenever the compiler gets into `scanf()` I am getting an error **segmentation fault**

Comment: Code formatting. Use it as well.

Comment: I don't think it is the **compiler** which gets into trouble here.

Comment: msg pointer points to random location instead of a buffer. That's why you get segmentation fault, when scanf try to store bytes to that random location.

Comment: so can u give me a solution for that?

Comment: Thanks Guys really i am new to this site and this is very useful site:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define msg as follow:

```
char msg[MSGSIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `scanf()`. You want to tell it to put the entered data somewhere. But you don't give it such a space.

Instead, you give it a pointer, which is uninitialized and therefore points to an unknown location. That leads to segfault.

You could use the `inbuf` instead.

But you should refrain from using `scanf()` in this way. If the user enters more data than your buffer can hold, weird things happen.

Instead, use `fscanf()`.